# Using one Samsung Gear Two DUID for multiple accounts

Tags: tizen-wearable-sdk, samsung-galaxy-gear

Samsung requires developers to register a DUID (Device Unique Identification) to a developer account to be able to test apps on the actual watch.
My question is. Can one DUID be registered on multiple accounts?
This is the scenario:
I have a watch and working on a app - the watch DUID is registered to my account - the handed off to my co-developer who also wants to register the watch DUID to his account and work on it. 
Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can. I just did this with two separate accounts. Each of you needs a separate author.crt.  If you can't get the "Permit to install applications" item to work in the Tizen IDE, manually delete the contents of /home/developer or reset the watch.